# OpenVPN server unable to start due to network issues

Tags: openvpn, networkmanager

I have been struggling with my OpenVPN server for a while now and i simply do not know how to correct the errors when i attempt to star the server. I have attached necessary information about my configurations, error and settings.

server.conf:

```
up "/etc/openvpn/up.sh br0"
down "/etc/openvpn/down.sh br0"
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tap0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

syslog:

```
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: OpenVPN 2.2.1 i686-linux-gnu [SSL] [LZO2] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [PF_INET6] [IPv6 payload 20110424-2 (2.2RC2)] built on Mar 30 2012
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet cafes that use the same subnet.
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1576 D:168 EF:68 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: /sbin/ifconfig tap0 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 10.8.0.255
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: /etc/openvpn/up.sh br0 tap0 1500 1576 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.0 init
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: WARNING: External program may not be called unless '--script-security 2' or higher is enabled.  Use '--script-security 3 system' for backward compatibility with 2.1_rc8 and earlier.  See --help text or man page for detailed info.
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: WARNING: Failed running command (--up/--down): external program fork failed
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow ovpn-server[9131]: Exiting
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow NetworkManager[873]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow NetworkManager[873]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb 12 15:24:24 buntopow NetworkManager[873]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
```

syslog after adding `script security 2` to config file:

```
Feb 12 16:24:27 buntopow ovpn-server[12655]: Listening for incoming TCP connection on [undef]
Feb 12 16:24:27 buntopow NetworkManager[873]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
Feb 12 16:24:27 buntopow ovpn-server[12655]: TCPv4_SERVER link local (bound): [undef]
Feb 12 16:24:27 buntopow NetworkManager[873]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Feb 12 16:24:27 buntopow ovpn-server[12655]: TCPv4_SERVER link remote: [undef]
```

The content of up.sh and down.sh is similar to the ones described on this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openvpn.html

I honestly do not know where to begin debugging this error and hope someone can point me to the right directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the suggestions here: http://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=21678.0 ?

Comment: `script-security 2` actually did the trick. But i am getting some other errors now even though the VPN server is infact running. I have updated my question.